# What are some heuristics for structuring scalable model relationships in Django?

Tags: django, data-structures

I don't know much about database structure. Nonetheless, I'd like to structure my models in such a way that is at least somewhat efficient. For example, I have the standard Django `User` model. When users sign up, they create a profile, select multiple activities (on an interface which shows available activities), and rank themselves according to said activities:

```
from django.db. import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class UserActivity(models.Model): 
    RANKINGS = (
            (0, '0 - Newbie'),
            (1, '1 - Advanced'),
            (2, '2 - Expert'),
    )
    activity = ForeignKey(Activity, related_name="activities")
    user = ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RANKINGS)

class Activity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
```

This seems fine and good to me, but often things seem fine and good and... well, they aren't. I'm wondering if there's a set of standards or heuristics that I can use for structuring models. What should I be thinking about when I create `ManyToMany` relationships, or `ForeignKeys` for example?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for having the `UserProfile` model? I mean you're only adding the `display_name`. Why not extend the `User` model? Also, you don't seem to have a relationship between `UserActivity` and any other `User` model. Is that intentional?

Comment: @saad I'm using the (django-registration)[https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/] app. right now, and it works out of the box with Django's default `User` model (this is a much simplified version of my models, but I'll be adding a lot more to the `UserProfile` model.) The lack of relationship between `UserActivity` and `UserProfile` was a typo! Thanks for pointing it out. :)